# aklog: a pioctl failed while setting tokens (18.04 LTS; afs daemon appears to be running)

Tags: 18.04, afs

I've become unable to use AFS in the past few days; aklog now yields

`aklog: a pioctl failed while setting tokens for cell [...]`

The standard advice seems to be to make sure the daemon is running, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Here a summary of my starting the service (for good measure; it seemed to be running anyway) and checking its status before encountering the problem again.

```
me@mine:~$ /etc/init.d/openafs-client start
[ ok ] Starting openafs-client (via systemctl): openafs-client.service.
mine:~$ sudo service openafs-client status
[sudo] password for me: 
● openafs-client.service - OpenAFS client
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openafs-client.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2019-08-22 11:59:48 BST; 31min ago
  Process: 3242 ExecStopPost=/sbin/rmmod $KMOD (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3241 ExecStop=/bin/umount -af -t afs (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3240 ExecStop=/bin/umount -a -t afs (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3236 ExecStop=/usr/share/openafs/openafs-client-postcheck (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3235 ExecStop=/bin/grep -qv ^1$ /proc/sys/kernel/modules_disabled (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3306 ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/fs sysname $AFS_SYSNAME (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3305 ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/fs setcrypt $AFS_SETCRYPT (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3304 ExecStart=/sbin/afsd $AFSD_ARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3294 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/openafs/openafs-client-precheck (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 22 11:59:48 mine afsd[3304]:        -fakestat-all             Enable fakestat support for all mounts
Aug 22 11:59:48 mine afsd[3304]:        -nomount                  Do not mount AFS
Aug 22 11:59:48 mine afsd[3304]:        -backuptree               Prefer backup volumes for mountpoints in backup volumes
Aug 22 11:59:48 mine afsd[3304]:        -rxbind                   Bind the Rx socket (one interface only)
Aug 22 11:59:48 mine afsd[3304]:        -settime                  set the time
Aug 22 11:59:48 mine afsd[3304]:        -disable-dynamic-vcaches  disable stat/vcache cache growing as needed
Aug 22 11:59:48 mine afsd[3304]:        -dynroot-sparse           Enable dynroot support with minimal cell list
Aug 22 11:59:48 mine fs[3305]: Usage: /usr/bin/fs setcrypt -crypt <on or off> [-help]
Aug 22 11:59:48 mine fs[3306]: Usage: /usr/bin/fs sysname [-newsys <new sysname>+] [-help]
Aug 22 11:59:48 mine systemd[1]: Started OpenAFS client.
mine:~$ aklog
aklog: a pioctl failed while setting tokens for my.cell
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to

1. Use PPA to get the latest version of openafs.
2. Explicitly (re)install openafs-client and other libraries.

I found a [blog post](https://blog.inf.ed.ac.uk/mingcanzhu/2017/04/16/conigure-openafs-on-ubuntu-16-04-based-on-kernel-4-8-x-x-generic/) that said to do the former, but in my case `apt-get update` wasn't sufficient to get things working for me.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openafs/stable
apt-get install openafs-client openafs-krb5 openafs-modules-dkms
```

I rebooted after this, but it might have sufficed to just restart the service.